# Как можно перетянуть изменения из одной ветки в другую, если начал разработку не в той ветке?

Tags: git

Коллеги, ситуация такая. Начал разработку в dev ветке по ошибке. Много чего уже там понаписал нужного. Добавил все это в отслеживание. Ничего пока не коммитил. Как бы мне все это дело перетащить в какую нибудь новую фича-ветку. А то, что в дев аннулировать к последнему коммиту?

Comment: 1. Черри-пик из той ветки в которую надо занести данные https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick 2. Переходим обратно в dev и старый-злой reset https://habr.com/ru/post/330722/

Comment: git stash можно, если вы создаёте для работы ветку от dev.

Answer (score 2):

Если эти изменения еще не зафиксированы, то достаточно создать новую ветку.

```
 git.exe checkout -b new-dev
```